# Modifying header variable in webmatrix/razor

Tags: json, razor, webmatrix, mandrill

I have a working header, below, which adds SMTP headers to outgoing emails:

```
var header = new[]{"X-MC-Template:RegisterTemplate", "Reply-To:myname@mail.com"};
```

I want to create a similar variable using the below code:

```
var tag = new[]{"X-MC-MergeVars", "var1", "hello1"};
```

and my webmail send function is as follows:

```
    WebMail.Send(to: customerEmail,
    subject: "test email",
    body: "email body",
    additionalHeaders: header, tag
```

but I don't know how to format it to work? My syntax is wrong, but I've tried many variations with now luck.

Comment: Sorry, completely forgot to add a very important part, this needs to be a JSON collection

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question, as I've never needed to add SMTP headers to emails before, but it would probably be helpful if you could add a little more info/examples to your question.

Comment: You know you are missing a closing parenthesis to your `WebMail.Send()` method in your code above, right?

Comment: yeah, that's just a copy and paste error, it's not missing in my code :) well caught though

Comment: Okay, just checking, just in case.